# Use of a functor on for_each

Tags: c++, stl, functor

Why does the `for_each` call on functor doesn't update `sum::total` at the end?

```
struct sum
{
    sum():total(0){};
    int total;

    void operator()(int element) 
    { 
       total+=element; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    sum s;

    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::for_each(arr, arr+6, s);
    cout << s.total << endl; // prints total = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`for_each` takes the functor by value - so it is copied. You can e.g. use a functor which is initialized with a pointer to an external int.

```
struct sum
{
    sum(int * t):total(t){};
    int * total;

    void operator()(int element)
    {
       *total+=element;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int total = 0;
    sum s(&total);

    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::for_each(arr, arr+6, s);
    cout << total << endl; // prints total = 15;
}
```

Or you can use the return value from `for_each`

```
struct sum
{
    sum():total(0){};
    int total;

    void operator()(int element) 
    { 
       total+=element; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    sum s;

    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    s = std::for_each(arr, arr+6, s);
    cout << s.total << endl; // prints total = 15;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`for_each` receives a copy of your functor by value. Even after that, it's free to copy it, but does return a copy.

OTOH, you're simply trying to re-invent `std::accumulate`, which will do the job much more easily:

```
int total = std::accumulate(arr, arr+6, 0);
cout << total << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the `s` which you pass to the `for_each` is by value. `for_each` accepts  it by value!

In C++0x, you can solve this problem with `for_each` as,

```
int sum  = 0;
std::for_each(arr, arr+6, [&](int n){ sum += n; });
std::cout << sum ;
```

Output:

```
15
```

Demo at ideone : http://ideone.com/s7OOn

---

Or you can simple write in the `std::cout` itself:

```
std::cout<<std::for_each(arr,arr+6,[&](int n)->int{sum += n;return sum;})(0);
```

Run : http://ideone.com/7Hyla

Note such different syntax is okay for learning purpose, as to how `std::for_each` works, and what it returns, but I would *not* recommend this syntax in real code. :-)

---

In C++, you can write user-defined conversion function in the functor as,

```
struct add
{
    int total;
    add():total(0){};
    void operator()(int element)  {  total+=element;  }
    operator int() { return total ; }
};

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int sum = std::for_each(arr, arr+6, add());
    std::cout << sum;
}
```

It's slightly different version from Erik second solution : http://ideone.com/vKnmA

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to std::for_each requires the functor to be passed by value .
A workaround for your solution:

```
struct sum
{
    sum():total(0){};
    int total;
    sum(sum & temp)
    {
        total = temp.total;
    }
    void operator()(int element) 
    { 
       total+=element; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    sum s;

    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    s = std::for_each(arr, arr+6, s);  // result of for_each assigned back to s
    cout << s.total << endl; // prints total = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::ref()` is also another option if you want your object state gets updated after std::for_each

```
struct Sum
{
    int total = 0;
    void operator()(int i) { total += i; }
};

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    Sum obj1;
    Sum t1 = std::for_each(arr, arr + 6, obj1);  // t1.total = 15 
                            // (Note: obj1.total = 0 bcos it is passed by value)

    Sum obj2;
    std::for_each(arr, arr + 6, std::ref(obj2)); // obj2.total = 15 (NO copy)

    Sum t2 = std::for_each(arr, arr + 6, Sum()); // t2.total = 15
}
```