# Implementation of references in functors

Tags: c++, functor

I've been trying to implement the top answer code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285970/use-of-a-functor-on-for-each?answertab=active#tab-top), but it keeps giving me the error "IntelliSense: argument list for class template "sort_vector" is missing" for the line where I'm trying to set up my reference below.

```
float answer = 0;
sort_vector s(&answer);
```

I'm launching my struct with this code

```
thrust::for_each(thrust::cuda::par.on(s1),
    d_idxs.begin(),
    d_idxs.end(), sort_vector<float>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_Ndata.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_Ddata.data()), s));
```

and my struct is set up like this

```
template <typename T> 
struct sort_vector
{

    T *Ndata;
    T *Ddata;

    sort_vector(T *_Ndata, T *_Ddata, float *a) : Ndata(_Ndata), Ddata(_Ddata), answer(a) {};
    float *answer;

    __host__ __device__ void operator()(int idx)
    {
        thrust::sort(thrust::seq, Ndata + idx*num_vals, Ndata + ((idx + 1)*num_vals));
        thrust::sort(thrust::seq, Ddata + idx*num_vals, Ddata + ((idx + 1)*num_vals));
        *answer = thrust::reduce(thrust::device, Ddata + idx*num_vals, Ddata + ((idx + 1)*num_vals));

    }
};
```

I can't seem to figure out why their code works and mine does not. I thought that maybe I am missing an include, but looked at other code implementing the same line of code and used their includes

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
```

yet it still didn't work.

Comment: Is it just the intellisense error or even the compilation fails ?

Comment: It does not compile either

Comment: Aren't you providing a wrong parameter (3rd parameter) while constructing `sort_vector` in `for_each`. It's expecting a `float` pointer, but you are passing it an instance of `sort_vector`

Comment: So when you use this call "sort_vector s(&answer);" you would need to call for_each with s instead as a way to pass the reference? Which of course would work well for the summing program I was trying to base my code off of.

Comment: No. My point is what is the need of `sort_vector s(&answer);` ? It won't compile in the place.  And in the `for_each` I would expect sort_vector to be created like this `sort_vector<float>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_Ndata.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_Ddata.data()), &answer)`

Comment: All I'm trying to do pass a variable that I can store the answer from the struct in so that I can access the new value. I just tried your second suggestion, however it created a memory conflict.